# Evaluate JavaScript returning empty list , but working in PowerShell and CMD

Tags: javascript, android, powershell, evaluatejavascript

I have two evaluate javascript one is returning a null value and the other is returning an emptylist[1] when the list size is not greater than 0

both of them were giving the output when run in PowerShell with node on the local Windows machine

here is the Android code

```
public void ProfileData(String url, AllMediaCallback callback) {
        final ArrayList<String>[] arrayOfLists = new ArrayList[3]; // Change the size to match the number of lists you need
        arrayOfLists[0] = new ArrayList<>(); // Initialize the first ArrayList
        arrayOfLists[1] = new ArrayList<>(); // Initialize the second ArrayList
        arrayOfLists[2] = new ArrayList<>(); // Initialize the third ArrayList
        AtomicInteger evaluationCounter = new AtomicInteger(); // Define the evaluationCounter here
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        // Delayed operation
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(() -> webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript: \n" +
                        "    const pressableContainers = document.querySelectorAll('data-pressable-container=\"true\"');\n" +
                        "    const profileImgUrls = [];\n" +
                        "    pressableContainers.forEach(container => {\n" +
                        "        const draggables = container.querySelectorAll('draggable=\"false\"');\n" +
                        "        draggables.forEach(draggable => {\n" +
                        "            const srcValue = draggable.getAttribute('src');\n" +
                        "            profileImgUrls.push(srcValue);\n" +
                        "        });\n" +
                        "    });\n" +
                        "    \n" +
                        "    profileImgUrls;\n", value -> {


                    Collections.addAll(arrayOfLists[0], value);
                    // Increase the evaluation counter
                    evaluationCounter.getAndIncrement();

                    // Check if both evaluations are done
                    if (evaluationCounter.get() == 3 && callback != null) {
                        callback.onAllMediiaStatusRecived(arrayOfLists);
                    }

                }), 2000);

                new Handler().postDelayed(() ->  webView.evaluateJavascript(
                        "javascript: \n" +
                                "    const pressableContainers = document.querySelectorAll('data-pressable-container=\"true\"');\n" +
                                "    const profileImgUrls = [];\n" +
                                "    pressableContainers.forEach(container => {\n" +
                                "        const videos = container.querySelectorAll('video');\n" +
                                "        \n" +
                                "        videos.forEach(video => {\n" +
                                "            const srcValue = video.getAttribute('src');\n" +
                                "            profileImgUrls.push(srcValue);\n" +
                                "        });\n" +
                                "    });\n" +
                                "    \n" +
                                "    profileImgUrls;\n", value -> {


                    Collections.addAll(arrayOfLists[1], value);
                    // Increase the evaluation counter
                    evaluationCounter.getAndIncrement();

                    // Check if both evaluations are done
                    if (evaluationCounter.get() == 3 && callback != null) {
                        callback.onAllMediiaStatusRecived(arrayOfLists);
                    }

                }), 2000);

               // Ignore this one its not related to evaluatejavascript 
                executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        try {
                            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                            Elements metaTags = document.getElementsByTag("meta");

                            for (Element metaTag : metaTags) {
                                String property = metaTag.attr("property");
                                String content = metaTag.attr("content");

                                if (property.equals("og:description")) {
                                    arrayOfLists[2].add(content);
                                }

                                if (property.equals("og:image")) {
                                    content = content.replace("&amp;", "&");
                                    arrayOfLists[2].add(content);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        handler.post(() -> {
                            // Increase the evaluation counter
                            evaluationCounter.getAndIncrement();

                            // Check if both evaluations are done
                            if (evaluationCounter.get() == 3 && callback != null) {
                                callback.onAllMediiaStatusRecived(arrayOfLists);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });


            }
        });


    }


    public interface AllMediaCallback {
    void onAllMediiaStatusRecived(ArrayList<String>[] ArrayOfLists);
}

 ProfileData(linkUrl, new AllMediaCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAllMediiaStatusRecived(ArrayList<String>[] ArrayOfLists) {
                
                    if (ArrayOfLists[0].size() > 0) {
                        for (String strImage : ArrayOfLists[0]) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strImage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Empty List[0]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    if (ArrayOfLists[1].size() > 0) {
                        for (String strImage : ArrayOfLists[1]) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strImage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Empty List[1]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                }
            });
```

And here is the node.js script, please note here I have used puppter for loading the webpage, as it is not needed in webview client in android

**Image.js**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Replace 'your_url_here' with the actual URL you want to load
  await page.goto('https://www.threads.net/@sagar_v_raval');

  // Wait for the content to load (you might need to adjust the selector and waiting time)
  await page.waitForSelector('[data-pressable-container="true"]');

  const srcValues = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const pressableContainers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-pressable-container="true"]');
    const srcValues = [];

    pressableContainers.forEach(container => {
      const draggables = container.querySelectorAll('[draggable="false"]');
      
      draggables.forEach(draggable => {
        const srcValue = draggable.getAttribute('src');
        srcValues.push(srcValue);
      });
    });

    return srcValues;
  });

  console.log(srcValues);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

**Video.js**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: 'new' });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Replace 'your_url_here' with the actual URL you want to load
  await page.goto('https://www.threads.net/@sagar_v_raval');

  // Wait for the content to load (you might need to adjust the selector and waiting time)
  await page.waitForSelector('[data-pressable-container="true"]');

  const srcValues = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const pressableContainers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-pressable-container="true"]');
    const srcValues = [];

    pressableContainers.forEach(container => {
      const videos = container.querySelectorAll('video'); // Select video elements with the 'video-class' class
      
      videos.forEach(video => {
        const srcValue = video.getAttribute('src');
        srcValues.push(srcValue);
      });
    });

    return srcValues;
  });

  console.log(srcValues);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but far as I know, browser will render html and Js line by line, while facing async/ await the function will go to event loop, so browser can keep rendering, call Js function in on page finished, could lead a possibility that html parsing is finish, but async/await function is not, therefore you execute your Js function before async/ await result back.

A simple way to verify this is using a button, you manually check website has right data, then trigger Js.

The other possiblity come to my mind is WebView does not support some methods, I believe mdn will mentioned those situations.

Comment: Actually the images is now loading , the only problem I have is the loading of the entire page , because the video takes time to load and the js get executed before the video is loaded so the video list get null , also sometimes images get null if the page is loading supper slow , so my probable solution is to wait for the page to be loaded 100% and check if all media has been loaded then only I want to execute both of the js script

Answer (score 1):

Use js to check if media elements loaded before running your main js code -  `window.onload` or `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {})` will do the trick.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript: \n" +
            "    window.onload = function() {\n" +
            "        // code here\n" +
            "    };\n", value -> {
            // android code here
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Nope the window.load is not working , i will try with the second one

Comment: and sorry the second method is also not working , returing a string value of 'null'

Comment: https://codeshare.io/Pd60Zw

Comment: 1. In the code you have profileVideoUrls; and srcValues; but they are not explicitly returned. You should use return profileVideoUrls; and return srcValues; at the end of your code.
2. Also postDelayed might not be reliable. Use js to check if the elements you're interested in are actually loaded like this:
webView.evaluateJavascript(
    "javascript: \n" +
    "    // Your code \n" +
    "    return profileImgUrls;", // Return it
    value -> {
        // Your Android code
    }
);
3. Btw make sure js is enabled in your WebView.
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: nope stil the same thing returns null in both , also increment the timeout to 10000 for both still not working , and also had checked the javascript is enabled , one ting im noticing is that the scroll method is not working in videos js when i add the eventlistner for waiting the page to be loaded completely , before that it was working find the js script was scrolling through the list , if there is chance of lazzy loading  , https://codeshare.io/Pd60Zw

Comment: I used JSON.stringify to convert the JavaScript array to a JSON string.
You're using Collections.addAll(arrayOfLists[1], value1); to add the data, but value1 might not be in the format you expect. You should parse this value into an ArrayList.
Also I used Gson to parse the JSON string to an ArrayList in Java.
https://codeshare.io/LwdyNK

Comment: Error :- 

Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object reference,

at this line arrayOfLists[1].addAll(list);

in my code i have added the video js script first and second is the img js script,, https://codeshare.io/dwqj9e

Comment: i have added the full error message now in https://codeshare.io/dwqj9e

Answer (score 0):

You are missing brackets I think. Change this line:

```
"    const pressableContainers = document.querySelectorAll('data-pressable-container=\"true\"');\n" +
```

To include brackets when querying for an attribute

```
"    const pressableContainers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-pressable-container=\"true\"]');\n" +
```

Comment: i had added it alredy but it was not working , now the images are shown but the videos are not , becuase when the page is loading the videos is taking a hughe amount of time to be loaded and as the script get run it is giving a null value for videos , also sometimes for the images , my new problem is to make sure all the kind of media on the page is loaded 100% and then only run the script

Comment: You will likely need to poll then. You can retry the snippet from android until you get a non-empty value or you can poll inside javascript and return a promise, but I think you will need to use javascriptInterface to get a value from async javascript. https://gist.github.com/timfreiheit/12a67124f1bb2a9572da. FYI, your sample code still doesn't show brackets. This is my best guess since I haven't used android webview javascriptInterface before

Comment: In your puppeteer program upon navigating to the site [add a script](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.addscripttag) to the client website. This script itself will await all other assets to be loaded before execution which can return an event once it executes by wrapping the logic within the script with a ```document.addEventListener('load', ... function```. In your puppeteer code listen to the event returned from the script. Then continue the execution of the puppeteer program.

Comment: In CSS selectors when you select an element based on its attribute value you need to wrap the attribute in square brackets. So it should look like this indeed: `'[data-pressable-container=\"true\"]'`